# Django: How to manipulate a Model object before adding it to DB?

Tags: python, django

In Python-Django, I've got a Model with a FileField member in it. This member stores video files.

I'd like to "interfere" with the standard "add model row/object/instance" proecdure of Django, and manipulate each video I'm adding, before actually *committing* or adding it to database.

The manipulation is to convert the video to a specific uniform format. Thus, all added videos will eventually be stored in the same format (*WebM*).

How can I do that? I've looked into Django's *custom managers*, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am actually doing this very same thing. You don't want to process the video file on the same request as it comes in on for several reasons:

1) You will hang the user on a non-responsive page for a long time, possibly timing them out and wondering if it worked.
2) And if they go to see if it uploaded - it still hasn't finished and saved in the DB (non-consistent) they'll think it is broken.

You want to initially save the record and file on your server. Mark it as needs-to-be-worked-on. And fire off a celery task that will do that work and update that flag when it is complete. I am actually doing this very same thing with zencoder for a project I am working on right now. It works wonderfully.

Celery: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery
Ghettoq (for local): http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ghettoq

Answer (score 5):

You can either override `save()` or use [signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch).

However, converting the video will take a lot of time. It is probably not a good idea to do that synchronously in your web request. A common approach is to offload the work to a task queue. Have a look at [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) for that.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use [django signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) to trigger events when items are about to be, or have been, saved to the database.

Specifically, you use the [Signal.connect()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.Signal.connect) method to connect the signal handler you want to launch, for example `pre_save`, `post_save`, `pre_delete`, `post_delete` etc.

In order to set things up:

**signals.py**:

```
from django.db.models.signals import *

def entry_action_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # what do we want to do here?
    pass

post_save.connect    (entry_action_post_save,        sender=Entry)
```

Where for me, `Entry` is a `models.Model` derived class.

This blog also covers an alternative way of setting it up using the [dispatcher in models.py](http://www.chrisdpratt.com/2008/02/16/signals-in-django-stuff-thats-not-documented-well/).

Note that since you are considering video encoding here, you might not want to actually re-encode the video inside these methods, otherwise your request will take forever to complete. A better method would be to check encoding, and have the model have a `status` field for `webM` or `notwebm`. Then pass off your encoding task elsewhere and do not display the video (`Videos.objects.filter(format='webm'`) until it is complete.

Answer (score 2):

You can just override the `save()` method on your model. See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).